# Your browser is completely ignoring the APPLET tag

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, applet

I am trying to view source code of a webpage made in `applet` with IE and Mozilla,
but I am unable to view the source code - it shows only:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title>*****************</title>
  <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Quanta Plus">
</head>
<body>
<applet width="100%" ******Applet.class 
    archive="*.jar"> 
Your browser is completely ignoring the &lt;APPLET&gt; tag!
</APPLET>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I find the source code for applet class?

Comment: What are you trying? firebug?

Comment: similar to that.All i need is that applet.class file or its source code

Comment: it's a bit unclear. where do you want to show that source? is t your own page?

Comment: the applet tag is deprecated in HTML4.01 and unsupported in HTML5. You should not use it but use ´<object>´ instead.

Comment: @Christoph, HTML5 requires continued support to `applet` (despite telling authors not to use it).

Comment: Please post the URL. The odds are that the actual source is as shown here, so the question is: which software or which person put that text into the element? (and what did you expect to see – the applet code? it’s not part of the HTML source).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela this element is not part of the official html5 spec but of course will still be supported like `marquee`. However you cannot/shouldn't rely on that!

Comment: Actually any compiled and running applet has never been shown its source code in HTML page at all (It is not JS etc)... so I guess the question conception is quite strange :S I may suggest author is asking about where the applet is downloaded or something? So then I can say author should check the "JRE cache viewer" for more details concerning the cache content or something... But sure it won't be the applet "source code" :) To see an applet source code you have to have the source code in your project src folder or you'll have to de-compile it :S